# Copy one value in if to other part

Tags: c++, if-statement

Hello I want to copy a value that I got in if so I can use it on the next part of the code how can I do that? I can't use the value of begin on the part of elapsed_secs Thank you

```
int temp = temp + 1;
if (temp == 1)
    clock_t begin = clock();
clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
gotoxy(50, 1); printf("Tiempo: %d", elapsed_secs);
```

Comment: Declare `clock_t begin`, outside `if`. And remember what to do if `temp != 1`

Comment: (1) What do you want to happen when `temp != 1`? (2) what value of `temp` do you want after `int temp = temp + 1;`?

Comment: You should read about Scopes in C++. And there is one thing thats unfortunately not very clear in many beginner texts. A local variable can only be used inside its scope. Contrary to what you seem to think, the local variable will be destroyed when you leave this local scope and when you enter the scope again (calling function twice), a new local variable will be created, so you can't assume the value from the previous run to be waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
int temp = <insert-initial-value>; // in your code it's used uninitialized!!!
clock_t begin = <insert-initial-value>;
if (temp == 1)
    begin = clock();
clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

since you want the scope of `begin` to be outside the body of the if-statement.

Moreover, you need to provide an initial value for `begin`, so that it won't be used uninitialized when computing `elapse_secs` (which would invoke Undefined Behavior).

---

EDIT:

From your comments, I believe that this is what you want to do (based on my [Time measurements](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

void functionToBeTimed(void) {/*do something here*/}

int main ()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "Executing the function twice...\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    functionToBeTimed();

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

  std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: but temp is not declared there I want the begin to execute just 1 time because I will run that function 2 times

Comment: What do you mean @CarlaPerez?

Comment: Where is temp initialized?

Comment: My goal is to just execute the clock_t begin 1 time because I will run the function 2 times

Comment: Thats not on main is a function

Comment: @CarlaPerez I think you are overcomplicating things. I updated my answer with a suggested solution. How does this looks?